# android in-app download/upgrade from market apk programmatically

Tags: android, google-play, in-app

if there's A apk and B apk and both are uploaded market (google play store),

1. does A can upgrade A apk from market without moving to play store?
   (user doesn't see play store activity, 
   and A apk just download A apk from market url)
2. does A can download B apk from market without moving to play store?

i found unofficial market api, but i want to know official way to do it.
Thanks,

@
i tested market api to download apk from market, 
then i got 404 error, and found that google changed login process to auth 2.0
is there anyone suceed to download from market programmatically without moving to play store?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can do like as you put apk to some of your server and on hitting on that url apk will be download. But it will not install till user open that apk.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the apk and store it on the phone's storage.
Then you can install that apk using this code,

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

This intent launches the install dialog with the user, where the user will choose to authorize permissions to the apk being requested to install.

But remember **there is no** official way to do this, there are many ways and according to me this seems like a good way to do this

Comment: Is there any way to download an apk from play store progammatically??